# Why my automation in Selenium webdriver is working slow for Internet Explorer browser?

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I had created a Test case for login in a website using internet Explorer server exe. When I Ran the script to enter the login name and password it takes 5 second to enter one character. Below are the details of the configuration done for this automation

- **IE Used**: IE Server 64 bit.
- **Editor Used** : Eclipse mars
- **OS Window** : 64 bit.

If you need any details ready to provide.
Can you guys tell me why it takes so much of time to enter the characters in the Login name and password. I ran same script for Chrome it works fine for me.
Note: Application works well on IE 8 and above versions. 
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Change the driver to 32-bit. Follow the link:

http://forumsqa.com/question/typing-too-slow-in-text-fields-while-replaying-tests/